# Multiple shutdowns for Upstart script

Tags: upstart

I need a script to shutdown differently depending on whether a user called `stop` or the system is going down.

Some background: I have two primary functionalities for ending a continuous process that I am running: `stop` and `suspend`. When I call `stop myscript`, I would like the `stop` functionality to be used. However, when the machine is shutting off, I would like the `suspend` functionality to be used. Is this possible with Upstart?

On a similar note, can I create a script-specific keyword that can specify my different shutdown types (such that I could say `stop myscript` AND `suspend myscript`)?

Answer (score 0):

Upstart doesn't have any "suspend" stanza, what you can do is to set up two upstart script with different `stop on` stanza.

Comment: I fail to see how this would in any way solve my problem....

Comment: @MirroredFate your problem has no solution, or more like that the only solution is using two files. Either way your approach is not possible with the current development of upstart. You can check http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/ and verify yourself.